# Issue with VectorUDT when using Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am writing an UDAF to be applied to a Spark data frame column of type Vector (spark.ml.linalg.Vector). I rely on spark.ml.linalg package so that I do not have to go back and forth between dataframe and RDD.

Inside the UDAF, I have to specify a data type for the input, buffer, and output schemas:

```
def inputSchema = new StructType().add("features", new VectorUDT())
def bufferSchema: StructType =
    StructType(StructField("list_of_similarities", ArrayType(new VectorUDT(), true), true) :: Nil)

override def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(DoubleType,true)
```

VectorUDT is what I would use with spark.mllib.linalg.Vector: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.scala

However, when I try to import it from spark.ml instead: `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` 
I get a runtime error (no errors during the build):

```
class VectorUDT in package linalg cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.ml.linalg
```

Is it expected/can you suggest a workaround?

I am using Spark 2.0.0

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Spark 2.0.0, the proper way to go is to use `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType` instead of `VectorUDT`. It was introduced in [this issue](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13789).

Comment: how did you find this?  i have worked with the spark codebase for four years but found this puzzling.

Comment: As a note: the source code has this `/**
 * User-defined type for [[Vector]] in [[mllib-local]] which allows easy interaction with SQL
 * via [[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset]].
 */
private[spark] class VectorUDT extends UserDefinedType[Vector] {` So there is no mention of  the `VectorType` there ..

Comment: I can't really remember how I found it, but I do remember that it took a long time.